# How to find a even number using a for loop contains n1 to n2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Am not getting it right. Why do I get an AssertionError for my function even_numbers?

```py
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    (n1, n2) = [-2, 4]
    for num in range(n1, n2 + 0):
        
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num, end = " ") 

n1, n2 = [-2, 4]
assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]
---------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-6544d23ef931> in <module>
          1 # Q6 Test Cases
    ----> 2 assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]
    
    AssertionError
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Printing is not the same thing as returning.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no research effort.

Comment: @BenKovitz: it is a possibility, but I'm not so sure. IMHO, it is probably more like a beginner's question, and they ran out of ideas of what to search for to solve their problem. I would err on the side of friendliness and being welcoming to beginners.

Comment: @Benkovitz thank you, i don't have any coding or computers science background, just trying to learn

Comment: @Hemanth To make a better question, please tell us things like: what ideas you've tried so far, what documentation you looked at, and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in the code.

First, the function overrides the arguments `n1, n2` by assigning `[-2, 4]` (perhaps a leftover of some debugging?)

Second, as noted in comments, the function filters adequately even numbers, but then prints them, and doesn't return anything.

You would like to return a `list` of all even numbers, so you need to collect them in a list, then return that.

You can just restructure your code as follow:

```py
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    return [num for num in range(n1, n2) if num % 2 == 0]

>>> even_numbers(-2, 4)
[-2, 0, 2]

assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]
```

Note how this is the same code as yours, and even in the same order, but turned into a list comprehension.

You can also keep the code even closer to your original:

```py
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    res = []
    for num in range(n1, n2):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            res.append(num)
    return res
```

Comment: Write a function even_numbers that uses a for loop and outputs a list that contains all the even numbers from  1  inclusive up to  2  exclusive and assert even_numbers(-2, 4) == [-2, 0, 2]

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what the function above does.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, when i run my variable even_numbers(-2, 4), the value returning as integers = -2, 0, 2 but i need it to return as a list when i run it [-2, 0, 2] i tried converting the integer or tupple into list but am getting too many errors which i am unable to apprehend.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is there a problem with either of the functions in this answer?

Comment: your solution helped thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What I first notice is that you are not returning anything from the code. So, as you want to return a list, you need to have one and append the values to it.

Also, why you added a **+0** to your range limit? The value will be the same. What you may want to do is subtract 1 because range will go from -2 to 3 if you don't do it.

You can do this (tried to make it simple so you understand everything in the code):

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    even_numbers_list = []
    for number in range(n1, n2-1):
       if number % 2 == 0:
          even_numbers_list.append(number)
    return even_numbers_list

>>> even_numbers(-2, 4)
[-2, 0, 2]
```

Also I advice you to add some logs (or prints) so you can understand better what are the errors of your code. Any question just ask ;)

Comment: This does __not__ return the requested values. It does effectively nothing, as it creates a list in the scope of the function and then appends to it, but never returns it

Comment: Ye I forgot to add the return statement. So it should be good now after I edited it. Thanks for the comment :)